# HTML5 Video Locks Up / Stops Playing After ~100 Seconds

Tags: javascript, video, video-streaming, html5-video

HTML5 video stop playing roughly about 100 seconds into playback. This happens on every video on try, and happens no matter which method of loading the video I have tried.

**Info**

For the sake of attempting to keep this brief, this is essentially a video streaming application. There are many different videos, and they will all be starting at a different startTime when loaded.

All videos are properly encoded & support streaming in chunks. All videos are .MP4

What I have tried:

**Setting Video SRC Attribute To Video URL**

I have tried setting the video src attribute to the URL pointing to the video, loading, setting the startTime, & playing. This stops at about 100 seconds of playback no matter where the startTime is set.

*I can pause the video wait a moment and start playing the video again and playback will resume, however it will eventually stop playing again.*

```
<video></video>

let video = document.querySelector( "video" );
video.src = "/media/S01E01.mp4";
video.load();
video.currentTime = 240;
video.play();
```

**If I check how many seconds have been buffered it shows the entire video has been buffered, yet still has this issue.**

```
video.buffered.end( 0 ) - video.buffered.start( 0 );

1383 // The Entire Length Of The Video In Seconds
```

**Downloading The Entire Video Using Fetch & Assigning The SRC As A Blob**

I thought this could be a buffering issue, so I tried changing the code to download the entire file using fetch & assigning the response as the SRC as a blob, and this ends in the same result with playback pausing / stopping after about 100 seconds of playback.

*I can pause the video wait a moment and start playing the video again and playback will resume, however it will eventually stop playing again.*

```
<video></video>

fetch( "/media/S01E01.mp4" )
.then( response => response.blob() )
.then( ( blob ) => {
    let video = document.querySelector( "video" );
    let src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    video.src = src;
    video.currentTime = 360;
    video.play();
})
```

**MediaStream API**

I have tried using the MediaStream API however because the video will start at random start times, I can't get the MediaStream API to work as I would like. I can get the video to play if I request the initial bytes of data of the video. If I attempt to request the entire video using the MediaStream API the fetch request aborts before it can finish with the error:

```
DOMException: The Operation Was Aborted
```

I am still working on attempting to use the MediaStream API by requesting the entire video in multiple requests, but I am still working on it, so I do not know the results as of yet. I am apprehensive to spend the time working on writing all of the code to get it working only for it to end in the same result.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does the file work anywhere else (_eg:_ a desktop media player like VLC)? Does it stop too if you simply use a URL to the MP4 on the video tag (no Blobs, no MSE)? PS: MSE expects a "fragmented" MP4 (aka ISOBMFF) so be sure your MP4 is chunked before you go to MSE. You can check by opening the file in some **hex editor** and look for `moof` text. If text is not found then your MP4 is not chunked. While in the hex editor also look for `senc` or `shaka` or `widevine` texts as these would confirm if there is some encryption included on the file.

Comment: To add to VC One's comment - if you can share a link to an example video that does not play this will help people check the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good practice to monitor video loading/readiness state, i.e.:

```
<video></video>

fetch( "/media/S01E01.mp4" )
.then( response => response.blob() )
.then( ( blob ) => {
    let video = document.querySelector( "video" );
    let src = URL.createObjectURL( blob );
    video.src = src;
    video.currentTime = 360;

    // monitor for errors
    video.onerror = () => {
      console.error(`Error ${video.error.code}; details: ${video.error.message}`);
    }

    // play the video as soon as the first frames are cached
    video.oncanplay = () => {
      video.play();
    };

    // or play when the entire video is cached
    video.oncanplaythrough = () => {
      video.play();
    };
})
```

Additionally, try to monitor the `video` tag.

- ready state https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState
- network state https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/networkState
- a stalled event to see if the server is not sending enough data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/stalled_event
- waiting event to see if a server is slow to serve data https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/waiting_event

These events and approaches should help you to get more insight into what is going on and why playback stops.

Let me know if this helps.

**Update based on comments**

If you say that `In Chrome it locks up the entire page.` it makes me think that there is a problem with a video driver. Chrome is using codecs integrated into it, so we cannot blame codecs installed on the machine.

As a first step, I would recommend checking and updating the video driver for your video card.

Another option is to try the same code on a different machine. If you don't have one, you can spin up Ubuntu without installing it and run your code. An alternative is to run a local HTTP server on your machine but open the webpage on your smartphone and see if the video plays there.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I just tried this and no error is thrown. The video stops about 60-100 seconds into playback and no error is thrown

Comment: The network tab in the development console shows the video request was successful and is fully downloaded.

Comment: Nothing really even fires. readyState has enough data and networkState is also good. The network tab shows it's downloaded the entire video, but it keeps stalling when playing. Waiting, stalled, nothing fires. It seems that nothing is wrong, but the video won't play more than 100 seconds at a time

Comment: @mcbeav Take a look at `chrome://media-internals/`.

Comment: @Brad This happens both in Firefox and Chrome, but in Firefox I can pause the video using the console, wait a moment and resume playing and the video will continue to play. In Chrome it locks up the entire page. Checking the /media-internals in chrome doesn't log any new data when the video locks up. Am I looking for something specifically?

Comment: @mcbeav It's probably going to come down to an issue with your graphics card... unlikely to be a reproduceable code problem.  Both Firefox and Chrome will use hardware accelerated codecs where possible.  You could try disabling those in your options and see what happens.

Comment: @mcbeav I've updated my answer with more options. Please check and let us know if anything works.

Comment: @mcbeav, I was wondering whether you had a chance to try the options I've suggested.

Comment: @RAllen I did, and it was helpful, I did resolve this issue, It was some weird bug with the OS. All videos in all players had this issue until I restarted. I hadn't restarted my machine in some time. Weird bug, but your answer was really helpful and I implemented it into my code for future use. I really appreciate the help and marked your answer as correct. Thanks!