# Html video player broken in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, video.js

I'm trying to stream live a CCTV camera. For that my microservice provide me a mp4 url. And I'm trying to play with HTML video player in Angular 9.

HTML

```
<video #videoTag id="video" controls="controls" preload="metadata" width="100%" height="250">
     Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<button (click)="playStream()">Play</button>
<button (click)="stopStream()">Stop</button>
```

ts.

```
@ViewChild('videoTag') videoTag: ElementRef;
playStream() {

  const videoUrl = 'DYNAMIC_VIDEO_URL'; 

  this.videoTag.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', videoUrl);
  this.videoTag.nativeElement.load();
  this.videoTag.nativeElement.play();
}

stopStream() {

  this.videoTag.nativeElement.setAttribute('src', '');
  this.videoTag.nativeElement.load();
  this.videoTag.nativeElement.pause();
}
```

My this code was working perfectly and this issue appear recently that on 1st attempt player only gather the data and showing loading symbol in player (I've checked in inspect -> network that data is continuously downloading) but now playing. After stop the player when I play it again then on 2nd attempt it's playing smoothing as I want.

**Note:** I've also tried to play same video with my older version of code where I faced the same issue. And I know those older version was perfectly fine. I use chrome for my application even I can see the same issue on Edge. Also I tried to change the player where I used video.js player and the result was same.

Please help me on this. thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to subscribe for `load` event of the `video` tag and execute `play` after enough data is downloaded. Another option is to set URL and subscribe on `canplaythrough` event and call `play` from it.
Check my other answer on a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75333050/html5-video-locks-up-stops-playing-after-100-seconds/75333237#75333237

Comment: Thanks to reply @RAllen I've tried with this fetch and play. But as I told you my scenario 1st attempt was only gathering data and on 2nd second attempt it's was playing smoothly. I am not aware but is that possible because of browser update or angular older version which I'm using?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with angular or browser. I would recommend trying to subscribe for events and see the sequence of events after `src` is set, as described in the answer I've mentioned above. This will help you to see what is actually going on with the tag. Try to remove the rest of the code i.e. `play`, `load`, and `pause`, and just assign `src` after handlers for events are set to log into the console. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the stages of the video loading. You can also check the network tab of the browser to see browser<->server interaction.